# Where is this EXCEL Sheet's data stored?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I am stuck at this problem which involves extracting data from a excel spreadsheet. And the values are "hidden" behind a "interface". I was given a excel file with the coordinate system and for the specified coordinates, when you click on them, a value is displayed to you on the small window above the spreadsheet.

I need all these values and I am sure that I could extract them all at once, not one by one.

So I need to gather all the values that are assigned to the specific coordinates and implement it in my program. Also there is this red-green interface which points out if the value is above a specified number.

But how do I get to the values?

[Excel Spreadsheet Link.](http://www.2shared.com/file/Zc87qLzt/Rot-Grn-Bilder_80kg_2000kg_bei.html)

Comment: Cells are formatted to not display (look at the Number format, it's `;;;` which means don't display the cell).  You can remove the formatting and expand the columns, or just `Copy` `PasteSpecial`, `Values` to another range or sheet to see the values.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have managed to change the format of numbers and they were shown. After this I saved the excel file as a cvs and now I have the data!

Answer (score 0):

They are stored in that row by column. The reason that you cannot see them when you open it is that the size of the column have been reduced. To see the actual number in the row by column, just expand that column by dragging it to the right. For example, in spreadsheet EEM_80_Eini+Ausi, if you look at cell B3 and expand the row and column, you will see the number .2450610558 inside that cell.

Comment: Yes I can see them but still one by one. And my goal is to be able to coppy them all at once. How could I do that?